# Test lower_bound's return value against the end iterator

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator, lower-bound

In effective STL by Scott Meyers (page 195) there is the following line:

"The result of lower_bound must be tested to see if it's pointing to the value you're looking for. Unlike find, you can't just test lower_bound's return value against the end iterator."

Can anyone explain why you can't do this? seems to work fine for me.

Comment: What is the context at that point in the book? It's confusing without knowing what the book is talking about. Is it saying for using `lower_bound` to see if a value is contained in the set?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works fine for you because your element is present.

`lower_bound` returns an iterator to the first element *not less* than the given value, and `upper_bound` returns an iterator to the first element *greater* than the given value.

Given the array `1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7`, `lower_bound(..., 5)` will return an iterator pointing to 6.

Hence, two ways of checking whether the value is present:

- Use `equal_range` to also get the `upper_bound` (computing separately `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` will probably be suboptimal). If the `std::distance` between the bounds is greater than 0 then the element is present.

  ```
  1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7
  std::distance(std::lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),5), std::upper_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),5)) == 0 // 6 is absent
  std::distance(std::lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),3), std::upper_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),3)) == 2 // 3 is present
  ```
- Compare the element pointed by the iterator with your value (provided operators `!=` and `<` are coherent), but you have to make sure it does not return the end iterator.

  ```
  *(std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 5)) != 5
  ```

Additionally, since `lower_bound` is a binary search algorithms it would be inconsistent to return `end` if the element was not found. Actually, the iterators returned by this algorithm can be used as a hint for a subsequent insertion operation for example.

Comment: +1: But as Meyers says in that book, comparing for equality won't always work (because `lower_bound` uses `<`, not `==`).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: If you override `<` you should probably override `==` as well. Adapted answer.

Comment: Even if you do, they won't necessarily correspond: `==` corresponds to "equality", `<` corresponds to "equivalence".  See Item 19 of Effective STL for a discussion of this.

Comment: If you overload `<`, you should also overload `==` in a compatible fashion (and `<=`, `>`, `>=` and `!=`).  The real issue is when you don't overload `<`, but pass a comparison operator to `lower_bound`.  In such cases, you have to use the same comparison function when checking after the call to `lower_bound`.